# Asp.net Typings not working

Tags: c#, typescript, typescript-typings, typelite

I'm using visual studio Angular2 mvc5 template and I changed model of it. And I generated model's typescript version with TypeLite. Now I have to reference the typescript but typescript system is not recognizing them even after rebuild project. It is referencing other file when I pressed F12 on model member.

Folder structure :

```
ProjectRoot/
 app
  some.component.ts
  ...
 Scripts
  ...
  TypeLite.Net4.tt
   TypeLite.Net4.d.ts
 typings (not included in project)
  main (same)
   ambient (same)
    TypeLite (same)
     index.d.ts (same)
 typings.json
 tsconfig.json
 ...
```

TypeLite.Net4.d.ts (represents updated model):

```
/// <reference path="Enums.ts" />

declare module Models {
    interface BpmGraph {
        Author: string;
        BpmPoints: Models.BpmPoint[];
        Id: number;
        SongName: string;
        Tags: string[];
        TimedBy: string;
    }
    interface BpmPoint {
        BpmMap: System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<number, number>[];
        BpmMap2: System.Tuple<number, number>[];
        Bpms: number[];
        GraphId: number;
        Id: number;
        Times: number[];
    }
    interface List {
        Count: number;
        CountEnded: number;
        Id: number;
        Name: string;
        Tasks: Models.Task[];
    }
    interface Task {
        Ended: boolean;
        Id: number;
        ListId: number;
        Name: string;
    }
}
declare module Models.ViewModel {
    interface JSONReturnVM<T> {
        element: T;
        errormessage: string;
        haserror: boolean;
    }
}
declare module System {
    interface Tuple<T1, T2> {
        Item1: T1;
        Item2: T2;
    }
}
declare module System.Collections.Generic {
    interface KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> {
        Key: TKey;
        Value: TValue;
    }
}
```

some.component.ts :

```
...
export class BpmHelperComponent {
    constructor(private _appService: AppServiceTodoList)
    {

    }


    get bpmGraph(): Models.List[]
    {
        return this._appService.todolist;
    }
...
```

Index.d.ts (what model member is referencing, not updated) :

```
// Generated by typings
// Source: scripts/TypeLite.Net4.d.ts
declare module Models {
    interface List {
        Count: number;
        CountEnded: number;
        Id: number;
        Name: string;
        Tasks: Models.Task[];
    }
    interface Task {
        Ended: boolean;
        Id: number;
        ListId: number;
        Name: string;
    }
}
declare module Models.ViewModel {
    interface JSONReturnVM<T> {
        element: T;
        errormessage: string;
        haserror: boolean;
    }
}
```

typings.json :

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts#56295f5058cac7ae458540423c50ac2dcf9fc711",
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654",
    "jquery": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jquery/jquery.d.ts#56295f5058cac7ae458540423c50ac2dcf9fc711",
    "TypeLite": "file:Scripts/TypeLite.Net4.d.ts"
  }
}
```

When I changed some.component.ts's Models.List to Models.BpmGraph, build fails saying "Build:Module 'Models' has no exported member 'BpmGraph"

What is correct way to update index.d.ts? It says 'Generated by typings' but I can't find a way to update that file.

I tried typings install but nothing changed except below message

```
PM> typings install --global
[?25h
+-- debug
| `-- ms
`-- mocha (global)
```

Comment: Run `typings install`.

Comment: @AlekseyL. I tried but nothing changed except below message in package manager console. PM> typings install
[?25h
+-- debug
| `-- ms
`-- mocha (global)

Answer (score 0):

Retried typings install after updating typings (0.8.3 to 2.0.0) and succeeded. typings install made new folder 'global' and some.component.ts is correctly referencing. I think this problem occurred because typings' ambient is renamed to global.